# Erro na execução do Evento em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Estou com um problema em JavaScript que indica que a linha está com erro, comparei com outros códigos mas não vejo nada de diferente dos outros códigos...

#### HTML

```
<script src="../js/contact.js" defer></script>


  <section id="support" class="row wide-container valign-wrapper">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 description">
      <h3><b>Precisa de ajuda?</b><br />Envie uma mensagem!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6 l6 form-container">
      <form wrapper="materialize_vertical_form" action="#!" method="post">
        <div class="input-field ">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
          <label class="required">* Nome</label>
          <div class="help-block grey-text"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field ">
          <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail">
          <label class="required">* E-mail</label>
          <div class="help-block grey-text"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field ">
          <textarea name="message" id="message" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
          <label class="required">* Mensagem</label>
          <div class="help-block grey-text"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field center-align">
          <button class="btn cta waves-effect waves-light btn-atendimento pulse-hover" type="submit" name="_sendMessage" id="_sendMessage">Enviar Mensagem</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="darken-backdrop"></div>
  </section>
```

#### Contact.js

```
window.onload = () => {
    //Constantes que são pegas do Formulário
    const name = document.getElementById('name');
    const mail = document.getElementById('mail');
    const message = document.getElementById('message');
    const sendMessage = document.getElementById('sendMessage');
(7) sendMessage.addEventListener('submit', (name, mail, message) => {

        if(name.value == undefined || name.value == "" || name.value == null){
            alert('Vazio!');
        } else {

        }
    });
}
```

Isso seria devido que ainda não fiz o que vai dentro do Else?

#### Erro

```
contact.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at window.onload (contact.js:7)
```

Comment: Ola @Devprogramacao, Bem vindo ao SOpt, você precisa adicionar o seu codigo `html` - [mcve] . Mas aparentemente o erro indica que o código `document.getElementById('sendMessage')` não esta encontrando um elemento com o id **sendMessage** no seu html.

Comment: Obrigado @Icaro e agradeço o acolhimento.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, já consegui solucionar o erro que estava dando nessa pergunta. era o sendMessage que estava com o id="_sendMessage".